# Error after Hibernate integration in my project

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish

### I'm trying to integrate Hibernate in my project but I receive this error:

Using GlassFish for my app server.

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: ClassCastException: attempting to cast
>   bundle://2.0:1/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to
>   jar:file:/Users/.../glassfish3/glassfish/modules/endorsed/jaxb-api-osgi.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.
>   Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.

Below is my `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/gestione_autotrasporti
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            admin
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            admin
        </property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: It appears you have 2 times the same class (javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext) in your classpath.  Since this class is provided by your application server (per Java EE spec), you should not add this class another time through a library dependency.  How is your classpath or how are the dependencies of your project defined?

Comment: I added to Eclipse all libraries contained in the "required" hibernate's folder:

antlr-2.7.7.jarclassmate-1.3.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.1.9.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar

Is this correct?

Comment: You can check the required dependencies for hibernate-core 5.1.9 here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.1.9.Final